# Firestore Pricing - RealTime Update listener count as one read or as number of data changes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore pricing it given that pricing is according to number of reads.

So if I use a realtime listner on value which changes, say every second then I will charged for one read or for as much as data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The billing for Firestore listeners is described on the [Firestore pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing):

> **Listening to query results**
>
> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get
>   realtime updates when the query results change.
>
> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
>   each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are
>   also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
>   because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is
>   deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
>   example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
>   if you had issued a brand-new query.

Comment: The language is not very clear to me. If you have 100 users listening to a query, and 1 user updates the result set, will I get charged 100 reads for each user listening or 1 read for the fact that the document was changed and had to be re-read?

Comment: @parliament Each connected user's read behavior is billed completely independently.  There is no bulk behavior.